# View by Taxonomy terms hide empty terms unless they have children

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I am trying to get my views block to display terms under this parent term but only show the terms with nodes in them. I managed to get this to work by using the relationship content with term and requiring the relationship. However we have terms with children that are empty but the children are not empty. I want it to display the term(without showing the children)

How do I make my views block display terms under parent term, remove the empty terms but show the empty terms with children?

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is:

> Taxonomy term: Representative node

This is a  [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421972/how-to-display-only-taxonomy-terms-with-nodes-associated-to-in-views-2), by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with views relationships and results can often be solved by reversing the order in which you construct (or think about) your relationships. Instead of making the parent term the central item of your view, do the following:

1. Create a taxonomy term view.
2. Add a required relationship to your term reference field.
3. Add a contextual filter for the parent term.